# Retrieve form data passed from javascript to flask python app

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I have a website that has a dynamic javascript table queried through mysql. The table lists devices, with a button on each row. When the button is pushed, the mac address in that row should be used to do another sql query to delete cells from that device.

I would like to do the sql query to delete cells from flask, but I am unable to get the mac address back in my flask app.

Here is the deleteCustomer and Post javascript functions:

```
function deleteCustomer(obj) {
    const data = obj.parentNode.parentNode.textContent;
    
    macIndex = data.search(":") - 2;
    mac = data.substr(macIndex, 17)

    var regex = /^([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})$/;
    test_flag = regex.test(mac)
    if (test_flag)
    {
        var index = obj.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
        var table = document.getElementById("deviceTable");
        //table.deleteRow(index);
        console.log("start")
        parameters = {
            value: mac,
            name: "mac"
        }
        post("/xgs/unassociate/device", parameters);
    }
}

/**
 * sends a request to the specified url from a form. this will change the window location.
 * @param {string} path the path to send the post request to
 * @param {object} params the parameters to add to the url
 * @param {string} [method=post] the method to use on the form
 */

function post(path, params, method='post') {

    // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
    // It can be made less verbose if you use one.
    const form = document.createElement('form');
    form.method = method;
    form.action = path;

    for (const key in params) {
    if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
        hiddenField.type = 'hidden';
        hiddenField.name = key;
        hiddenField.value = params[key];

        form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    }
    }
    console.log(form);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

Here is the flask app route to be called:

```
@app.route('/xgs/unassociate/device', methods=['POST'])
def unassocCust():
if session.get('logged_in'):
    user = app_users.get_user()
    if app_admin.get_permissions()['xgs']:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print("Step 1")
            mac = request.form["mac"]
            print("Step 1.5")
            result = app_xgs.xgs_unassociateCustomer( mac )
            data = app_xgs.xgs_devices_with_cust()
            print("Step 2")
            return render_template('xgs_unassociate.html', user=user, permissions=app_admin.get_permissions(), data=data)
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('page_not_found'))
else:
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

And finally the script that gets called to present the table.

```
<div id='container'>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        myVar = returnData({{data|tojson}})
        document.getElementById('container').innerHTML=createTable(myVar, "unassociate");
    </script>
</div>
```

The line mac = request.form["mac"] is causing me issues, I can see the mac being sent to the post(path, params, method='post') func from the javascript console, and my webpage goes to the /xgs/unassociate/device page, but back in flask the request.form["mac"] is causing the 400 Bad Request, as I only make it to the "step 1" flask print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, in my post function, the actual 'name' of the mac address was 'value', since its a general post function.

```
if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    const hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenField.type = 'hidden';
    hiddenField.name = key;
    hiddenField.value = params[key];

    form.appendChild(hiddenField);
}
```

So I needed to use "value" instead of "mac" for my form request. Although I expected the hiddenField.name to be what I needed, not sure why to include it in the parameter variable at this point.

```
mac = request.form["value"]
```